# Datagridview Checkbox doesn't count as checked before leaving it

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

I have Datagridview with 4 columns for check boxes and 5 rows ( like matrix of check boxes). when the user checks his desired checkboxes and press a button "Save", the last edited check box will not be changed unless the user go to any other cell ( without changing anything, just move from the cell).
I don't know how to fix that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_permissions.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    paramList.Clear();
    paramList.Add("uGrpPermissionModule", dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());                    
    paramList.Add("uGrpRead", Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString()));
    paramList.Add("uGrpNew", Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString()));
    paramList.Add("uGrpUpdate", Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
    paramList.Add("uGrpDelete", Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
    paramList.Add("uGrpReports", Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_permissions.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()));
    try
    {
        retval = DBFucntions.doWriteCommand(sqlStr, paramList);                 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has to do with the fact that there isn't really a proper editing control with the check box columns. Whenever I run into this issue, I use the following event handler for the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event on the `DataGridView`:

```
private void DataGridView_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.mDataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty &&
        (this.mDataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == /* check box column */))
    {
        this.mDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```